# Why does position:fixed on the right and left containers break this layout?

Tags: html, css

I want the containers to stick while you scroll down the page, but when I add "position:fixed" it breaks the layout for some reason, making everything go over to the left. i added the code with position:fixed added to the containers, and here's an example of what it's supposed to look like without:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRQG2.png)

```css
body {
    font-family: arial;
    background: #222;
}


img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}


#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 100px 0 100px 0;
}


#container_left {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 14;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
}


.post {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 80px 0 80px;
}


#container_right {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 14;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
}

.text_container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}


.text {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}


.text p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <div id="wrapper">

            <div id="container_left">
                <div class="text_container">
                    <div class="text">
                        {block:Description}
                        <div
                            style="height:auto;max-height:112px;overflow:auto;scrollbar-width:thin;padding:0 3px 0 3px;">
                            {text:Description}</div>
                        {/block:Description}
                    </div> <!-- text -->
                </div> <!-- text container -->
            </div> <!-- container left -->

            <div class="post">

                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                dolore magna aliqua. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus. Viverra suspendisse
                potenti nullam ac tortor vitae purus. In metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis. Odio morbi quis commodo
                odio aenean sed. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis. Eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur
                lorem. Mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien. Mollis nunc sed id semper.
                Bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed. Nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim
                nec. Id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu. Adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum. Pretium quam
                vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante. Tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan
                in. Suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Tellus at urna condimentum mattis
                pellentesque id nibh tortor id. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Amet facilisis
                magna etiam tempor orci eu. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam.

            </div> <!-- post -->

            <div id="container_right">
                <div class="text_container">
                    <div class="text">
                        <div
                            style="height:auto;max-height:112px;overflow:auto;scrollbar-width:thin;padding:0 3px 0 3px;">
                            {text:Extra Box}</div>
                    </div> <!-- text -->
                </div> <!-- text container -->
            </div> <!-- container right -->

        </div> <!-- wrapper -->
    </div> <!-- center -->
</body>
```

Comment: `position:fixed` removes elements from page flow. Try using `display: flex;` for parent element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found some issues and have fixed that. Some points that I have noticed are.

1. Specify `right/left` with `bottom/top` values for `fixed` positioned elements to make them fixed at a position.
2. Use `margin: 0 auto` inorder to align the center portion.
3. Never make use of `float` along with `margin: 0 auto`. Using `float` will prevent `margin: 0 auto` from its desired behaviour.

Hope this is helpful.

```css
body {
    font-family: arial;
    background: #222;
}


img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}


#wrapper {
    /* width: 1000px;
    margin: 100px 0 100px 0; */
    width: 100%; /* Use your desired width*/
}


#container_left {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 14;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}


.post {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    /* float: left; :Using float will break the margin:0 auto to break*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}


#container_right {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 14;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    /* float: left; :Using float will break the margin:0 auto to break*/
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.text_container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}


.text {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}


.text p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div align="center">
      <div id="wrapper">

          <div id="container_left">
              <div class="text_container">
                  <div class="text">
                      {block:Description}
                      <div
                          style="height:auto;max-height:112px;overflow:auto;scrollbar-width:thin;padding:0 3px 0 3px;">
                          {text:Description}</div>
                      {/block:Description}
                  </div> <!-- text -->
              </div> <!-- text container -->
          </div> <!-- container left -->

          <div class="post">

              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
              dolore magna aliqua. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus. Viverra suspendisse
              potenti nullam ac tortor vitae purus. In metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis. Odio morbi quis commodo
              odio aenean sed. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis. Eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur
              lorem. Mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien. Mollis nunc sed id semper.
              Bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed. Nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim
              nec. Id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu. Adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum. Pretium quam
              vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante. Tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan
              in. Suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Tellus at urna condimentum mattis
              pellentesque id nibh tortor id. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Amet facilisis
              magna etiam tempor orci eu. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam.

          </div> <!-- post -->

          <div id="container_right">
              <div class="text_container">
                  <div class="text">
                      <div
                          style="height:auto;max-height:112px;overflow:auto;scrollbar-width:thin;padding:0 3px 0 3px;">
                          {text:Extra Box}</div>
                  </div> <!-- text -->
              </div> <!-- text container -->
          </div> <!-- container right -->

      </div> <!-- wrapper -->
  </div> <!-- center -->
</body>
```

Want to get rid of this positioning overheads? Go for flex. its just awesome. Here is a sample implementation for your question.

```css
body {
    font-family: arial;
    background: #222;
    overflow: hidden;
}


img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}


#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}


#container_left {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 14;
    /* width: 150px; */
    /* height: auto; */
    text-align: center;
}


.post {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    /* width: 500px; */
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


#container_right {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 14;
    /* width: 150px; */
    /* height: auto; */
    text-align: center;
}

.text_container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}


.text {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}


.text p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div align="center">
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div>
          <div id="container_left">
              <div class="text_container">
                  <div class="text">
                      {block:Description}
                      <div
                          style="height:auto;max-height:112px;overflow:auto;scrollbar-width:thin;padding:0 3px 0 3px;">
                          {text:Description}</div>
                      {/block:Description}
                  </div> <!-- text -->
              </div> <!-- text container -->
          </div> <!-- container left -->
        </div>
          <div class="post">

              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
              dolore magna aliqua. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus. Viverra suspendisse
              potenti nullam ac tortor vitae purus. In metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis. Odio morbi quis commodo
              odio aenean sed. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis. Eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur
              lorem. Mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien. Mollis nunc sed id semper.
              Bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed. Nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim
              nec. Id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu. Adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum. Pretium quam
              vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante. Tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan
              in. Suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Tellus at urna condimentum mattis
              pellentesque id nibh tortor id. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Amet facilisis
              magna etiam tempor orci eu. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam.

              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
              dolore magna aliqua. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus. Viverra suspendisse
              potenti nullam ac tortor vitae purus. In metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis. Odio morbi quis commodo
              odio aenean sed. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis. Eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur
              lorem. Mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien. Mollis nunc sed id semper.
              Bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed. Nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim
              nec. Id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu. Adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum. Pretium quam
              vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante. Tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan
              in. Suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Tellus at urna condimentum mattis
              pellentesque id nibh tortor id. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Amet facilisis
              magna etiam tempor orci eu. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam.

          </div> <!-- post -->
          <div>
          <div id="container_right">
              <div class="text_container">
                  <div class="text">
                      <div
                          style="height:auto;max-height:112px;overflow:auto;scrollbar-width:thin;padding:0 3px 0 3px;">
                          {text:Extra Box}</div>
                  </div> <!-- text -->
              </div> <!-- text container -->
          </div> <!-- container right -->
        </div>
      </div> <!-- wrapper -->
  </div> <!-- center -->
</body>
```

Comment: this was extremely helpful i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

With position fixed you need to set a left/right property instead of a float.
Try changing the right container to the code below and then adjust your other css accordingly:

```
#container_right {
  border:1px solid red; 
  background:#fff;
  font-size:14;
  width:150px;
  height:auto;
  text-align:center;
  position:fixed;
  right: 10px;
}
```